# Why does animate package produce a strange PDF file that always prompts us before closing?

Tags: pdf, viewers, animate, adobe

```
% test.tex
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
Why does animate package produce a strange PDF file \\that always prompts us before closing?
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a known issue with the current version of the Adobe reader.  It's not an issue with LaTeX.  At least that's what my research on this has revealed when I've had to deal with the same annoying message.

Comment: Fortunately it does *not* always prompt for saving: Just add 1 animation. Thus, if you don't insert animations, omit `\usepackage{animate}`.

Comment: Some folks in the Adobe forums insist [this is not a bug](https://forums.adobe.com/message/10562427#10562427) with no explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While loading `animate`, the command

```
\pdfcatalog{/AcroForm <</Fields []/NeedAppearances true>>}
```

is executed.

Strangely, the sheer existence of the `AcroForm` dictionary in the PDF catalog causes Adobe Reader to prompt for saving when the document is closed, and even more strangely, yet fortunately, it does *not*, if there is at least one animation in the document.

To avoid the message, just omit `\usepackage{animate}` if there are no animations (which sounds quite natural).

**EDIT**

The same happened with the `media9` package. (It uses Form Fields for creating buttons and also executed the above line of code by default.) Both packages have been fixed, updates being available on CTAN or, very soon,
 via `tlmgr`.